# How can I convert this linq expression to method form?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

How can I convert this linq

```
from f in fake
join r in real
on f.Year equals r.Year
into joinResult
from r in joinResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
select (r == null ? f : r);
```

in Linq with method form.

```
fake.Join(real, ...)
```

Is there a tool that could help me to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what ReSharper converted it into:

```
fake.GroupJoin(real, f => f.Year, r => r.Year, (f, joinResult) => new {f, joinResult})
    .SelectMany(@t => @t.joinResult.DefaultIfEmpty(), (@t, r) => (r == null ? @t.f : r));
```